# URI for this MEAN tutorial?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

VS Code version 1.15.1, 
Node 7.4.0
In this good [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/mongoose) of MEAN, scroll to the bottom for

> Testing - create some items

Ran 1 and 2, no problem. 
Based on the on-screen [image: hint] at mLab.com, ran 3 in Terminal with the URI:

> node populate
>   "mongodb://ImDbUser:DbPsd@ds12345.mlab.com:12345/myCollection"

rejected by

```
if (!userArgs[0].startsWith('mongodb://')) {
    console.log('ERROR: You need to specify a valid mongodb URL as the first argument');
    return
}
```

Confirmed `console.log("[0]==" + userArgs[0]);` returns the URI. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you don't need to put quote around URI, try:

```
node populate mongodb://ImDbUser:DbPsd@ds12345.mlab.com:12345/myCollection
```

Comment: Did try, same. Did you get diff result?